# Что за ошибка StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, исключения

Вылетает ошибка java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 при деплое приложения на ibm websphere. Первый раз сталкиваюсь с данной ошибкой и не могу представить в чём может быть проблема. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 3):

Обращаетесь к несуществующей части строки.
Например:

```
String s = "new";
System.out.println(s.charAt(666));
```